# Local cgi server

Tags: python, lamp, cgi

I'm doing some python cgi programming and was wondering if there was a script for running cgi instead of having to install an entire LAMP server for doing it. I've been using CGIHTTPServer but it requires a cgi-bin folder in which to run the scripts. I want something that can run in the home folder but doesn't require LAMP to be installed. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to install a server but not a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP), just a webserver that is either Apaceh, Nginx or whatever server you like.

Python's CGIHTTPServer require the cgi-bin folder. In the other hand say with Apache you can specify how to handle cgi scripts and the directories containing them. For example in my development server (Apache) i run cgi python scripts from a directory located at ~/projects/scripts.

Comment: Well, I'm currently doing a redirect from CGIHTTPServer root folder to my index.py script. To go into further detail, I am deving a p2p social network where each user runs a cgi server locally. This server is how the entire network works. I don't want to install apache as it seems such a waste to install a full webserver for the simple task of returning a few lines of information. Is there anything wrong with running such a system from CGIHTTPServer for all my users?